# Как вопроизвести CSRF атаку на свой сайт?

Tags: веб-программирование, http, csrf

В интернете множество статей на тему, как внедрить CSRF токен.
Но я так и не смог понять для себя смысл этого токена, везде говорится, что он нужен для того, что если сделать POST форму на другом сайте и направить её на свой сайт, где я авторизован, то она отработает, так как cookies передадутся, но только я еще лет 5 назад знал, что cookies не передаются при таком подходе. POST запрос с другого сайта прилетит в этом случае без cookies (вернее прилетят только те cookies, у которых принудительно изменена опция same site).

В итоге есть какая-то недосказанность на тему, когда именно нужно использовать CSRF защиту, о которой не упоминают повсеместно. На данный момент я вижу, что защита нужна только в том случае, когда у авторизационных cookies (cookies для авторизации и сессии) почему-то вдруг решили изменить зону видимости через опцию same site. Или я ошибаюсь?

На счет старых браузеров не знаю, но я уже давно (наверно около 5 лет назад) наблюдал поведение, когда cookies не передавались при CSRF запросах.

На данный момент я не могу проверить значимость CSRF для своего сайта, так как не могу воспроизвести CSRF атаку. Я что-то упускаю?

Comment: *cookies не передаются при таком подходе* — и 1000 лет назад и сейчас куки отлично передаются (если не озаботиться простановкой флага `SameSite`)

Comment: Плюс всё ещё есть старые браузеры которые ничего не знают про `SameSite` (IE, например)

Comment: IE я уже не рассматриваю, он нем забыли как как и о Windows XP.

Comment: Вы может и забыли, а корпорации помнят

Comment: У вот https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite получается по умолчанию в какой-то момент изменился стандарт.

Comment: Ну поменялся на `Lax`. Что вообще не помешает мне отправить вам POST-запрос в который уйдут все куки

Comment: `<form action="yoursite/transfer-all-your-money-to-me" method=POST id=f></form><script>f.submit()</script>` и всё. Это навигационный переход, так что все куки будут и всё отлично выполнится.

Comment: Не работает. Описал же, беру форму с основного сайта, развертываю её на другом, делаю submit, перехожу на основной сайт с post запросом, но cookies там нет.

Comment: Хотя кука сессии передалась. Можно конечно это вылечить настройками самой этой куки, но на всякий случаю сделаю CSRF токен. Спасибо.